# JRuby and GEMS_PATH

Tags: ruby, path, rubygems, jruby

I'm trying to make a JAR with a Ruby Sinatra-based script, so I need to access to some gems.

I try to install them like that:

```
$ jruby -S gem install sinatra sqlite3 json              
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
You don't have write permissions into the /usr/share/jruby/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 directory.
```

Is their a way to put them in my home directory?
I use Fedora 17 i686 and JRuby 1.6.3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can [install the gems](http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/10#page33) in a specific directory using the `-i` option:

```
$ gem install -i /path/to/location sinatra sqlite3 json
```

Then set the `GEM_PATH` variable to `/path/to/location/gems`.